# Extract a particular word at a particular position in a line using Python

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a set of lines in a file like below.

mov             66 (56.9%)        5406720 (56.9%)

I want to identify these lines in a set of files and extract the first (mov) and  fifth field (5406720 in the above case) and write this to a separate single file.

Thanks & regard,
santosh

Answer (score 2):

It’s easy. 
First open your file and read each line

```
With open(file name, ‘r’) as f:
    Line = f.readline()
    Data = Line.split(“ “)
    If “mov” is Data[0]:
        Nf = open(new file,’w’)
        Nf.write(Data[0]+” “+Data[4]
        Nf.close()
```

This will open your text file. Read each line and look for lines starting with “mov” and if so create and write a new file with “mov” and your fifth field.

Comment: Please make sure you do not use `‘r’` smart quotes in your posts. People cannot cut and paste your code if you do.